# Windows File Share Not Accessible From Only One Specific Machine On Network

Tags: networking, windows-10, network-shares, nas

I have a WD 'My Cloud' NAS device on my home network.  It is configured to share files at '\\Nas\'.

I also have several other devices on my network

- Desktop PC (RobsPc)
- Laptop PC  (RobsLaptop)
- Netbook    (RobsNB)

All three are running Windows 10 and all have their own shared folder accessible to everyone by \Shared.  So \\RobsPc\Shared\ or \\RobsLaptop\Shared\ will give you access to anything in the shared folder.

This has been my setup for months.  About two weeks ago, RobsPc stopped being able to connect to \\Nas\ via Windows Explorer.  It fails with a 'The network path was not found' error.  Error code 0x80070035' message.

From RobsPc I can successfully 'ping nas'.  I can FTP to the nas device.  I can http to the nas device.  But I cannot access the windows share.  I also cannot access the share via ip.  However, I can access every single other device's shared folder.  Just not the nas device.

From every other device on the network I can reach \\nas\ as well was \\RobsPc\'s shared folders.

I've completely disabled the firewall on RobsPc and reset the settings on the nas to their defaults.  I've checked the router for any crazy forwarding rules or similar and basically a whole bunch of seemingly unlikely solutions (run SFC, disable IPv6, disable and enable netbios) based on internet searches.

Can anyone help me diagnose this problem?

Additional Information:

- The NAS doesn't appear to have the ability to restrict access by machine name or MAC address.
- I dual-boot Linux.  From Linux I am able to access the NAS from RobsPC
- I cannot access the NAS from any user account on RobsPC

Comment: https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/forum/windows_10-networking-winpc/windows-10-explorer-network-error-0x80070035-the/f30a1112-ffa7-4230-b843-ecc7ab8b5119

Answer (score 1):

To troubleshoot some more I would try and create another share on \NAS see of that works. If it does then you know it's a security or permissions issue with that share. If it doesn't then I would continue to look at the system.
Can you telnet into ports associated with file sharing?

Microsoft file sharing SMB:
User Datagram Protocol (UDP) ports 135 - 139
Transmission Control Protocol (TCP) ports from 135 - 139.

Otherwise if this is a Windows 10 environment it could be related to SMB versions that an update changed.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like there are a lot of potential causes/solutions to this issue.  In my particular case I was able to resolve this by inspecting the logs of my NAS device.  RobsPC was sending the currently logged in Windows Live Acount (rob@hotmail.com) to the NAS and the NAS was reporting that this user did not have access.

Previously, Windows Explorer would prompt me for credentials; but it doesn't anymore.

Instead of access the drive via \\Nas\ I used the Map Network Drive dialog to specify the credentials.

Right-click on 'Network' and select 'Map Network Drive'

[image: MapNetworkDrive]

Check the box for 'Connect using different credentials'

Answer (score 0):

If you are using public (anonymous) SMB shares on the WD My Cloud device (for example a My Cloud PR4100) and are seeing the error "Error code: 0x80070035
The network path was not found" when trying to browse to the server or its shares, you'll need to enable a feature in Windows called "Enable insecure guest logons".

To do this:

1. Open the Local Group Policy Editor (run gpedit.msc)
2. Navigate to Computer Configuration -> Administrative Templates -> Network -> Lanman Workstation
3. Set "Enable insecure guest logons" to Enabled

[image]

On Windows 10 2004 and newer, the above policy may no longer work on Home or Professional Editions. In this case you'll have to make the change directly in the registry by setting the following value to 1:

HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Services\LanmanWorkstation\Parameters\AllowInsecureGuestAuth